# React Native + Android: Release build "Unfortunately App, has stopped"

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to prepare my app for release.

When I run the app from android studio it works fine. But when I upload a beta build to the Play Store or I run `adb install android/app/app-release.apk` and try to run the app on my phone, it shows the `Unfortunately App, has stopped` message.

How can I debug this? Is there a way to run the release build on my phone through android studio so that I can view the logs?

Comment: You can install a logcat app from the playstore. You probably could get `adb logcat` to work too

Comment: ooooo adb logcat prints stuff when I open the app! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never tried, but leave your device plugged in to USB. Run `adb logcat` in the terminal.

There's probably additional settings to filter for your specific application package